# How to send two request with postman?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, postman

I send this with postman in the body :

{
"username": "jeantille",
"mail": "jeantille@gmail.com",
"password": "motdepasse"
}

I think that i have to send two request at different time but I can't. Can you help me please.

controllers/user.js

```
exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {
    
    User.findOne({
        attributes: ['mail'],
        where: {  
            mail: req.body.mail
        }
    })
    .then(userExist => {
        if(!userExist) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
            .then(hash => {
                const user = User.build({
                    username: req.body.username,
                    mail: req.body.mail,
                    password: hash,
                    admin: 0
                });
                user.save()
                    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Votre compte a bien été créé !' }))
                    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error: '⚠ Oops, une erreur s\'est produite !' }));
            })
            .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: 'Une erreur s\'est produite lors de la création de votre compte' }));
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Cet utilisateur existe déjà' })
        }
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: '⚠ Oops, une erreur s\'est produite !' }));
};
```

Comment: What happens when you send two requests via postman?

Comment: i don't arrived to send two request because i have this :

Comment: Executing (default): SELECT `mail` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`mail` = 'jeantille@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`mail`,`password`,`admin`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);

Comment: I send that with postman : {
    "username": "jeantille",
    "mail": "jeantille@gmail.com",
    "password": "motdepasse"
}